# Exclude multiple custom post types from search

Tags: custom-post-types, search

I'm trying to exclude a couple of custom post types from search results. The following works for one post type:

```
// Exclude custom post types from search
add_action('init', 'cdxn_remove_custom_type_from_search', 99);
function cdxn_remove_custom_type_from_search() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    if (post_type_exists('videos')) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['videos']->exclude_from_search = true;
    } 
}
```

If I build on this the first type is excluded but the second is not:

```
// Exclude custom post types from search
add_action('init', 'cdxn_remove_custom_type_from_search', 99);
function cdxn_remove_custom_type_from_search() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    if (post_type_exists('videos')) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['videos']->exclude_from_search = true;
    } elseif (post_type_exists('coordinator')) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['coordinator']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't a WordPress problem, it's a generic programming problem, a misunderstanding of how `if` and `else` statements work

Answer (score 0):

```
// Exclude custom post types from search
add_action('init', 'cdxn_remove_custom_types_from_search', 99);
function cdxn_remove_custom_types_from_search() {
    global $wp_post_types;

    if (post_type_exists('videos')) {
        // exclude 'videos' from search results
        $wp_post_types['videos']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }

    if (post_type_exists('coordinator')) {
        // exclude 'coordinator' from search results
        $wp_post_types['coordinator']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
}
```

This code is working, I have tried it in local with xampp, I created the 2 post types (videos, coordinator) and added 1 post in each one of them, when I searched them, it only showed the pages and articles.

Your code was not working because, you are using "elseif" which it creates a conditional structure where only one of the conditions will be evaluated, and the first one that is true will execute, skipping the rest.

I hope I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `elseif` doesn't work the way you think it does. You're trying to use it in a way that's closer to a `switch` statement or multiple `if` statement`

This:

```php
    if (post_type_exists('videos')) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['videos']->exclude_from_search = true;
    } elseif (post_type_exists('coordinator')) {
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['coordinator']->exclude_from_search = true;
    }
```

Is the same as this:

```php
    if (post_type_exists('videos')) { // if videos exists
        // exclude from search results
        $wp_post_types['videos']->exclude_from_search = true;
    } else { // if it does not exist
        if (post_type_exists('coordinator')) {
            // exclude from search results
            $wp_post_types['coordinator']->exclude_from_search = true;
        }
    }
```

`else if` just shortens things so that it's more readable and takes less time to type. It's called syntactic sugar.

If you want to check multiple things in a row, then you should use multiple `if` statements in a row:

```php
if ( condition1 is true ) {
    // do a thing
}

if ( condition2 is true ) {
    // do a thing
}
```